# use swift to create object instances through UI button

Tags: ios, swift, class, uiimageview, uibutton

I am trying to create an instance of an `UIImageView` in an app that I'm working on so that it can be put in to my view and editable.

I'm fairly new, so I have not even yet figured out, if there is a way, to create an instance of a class without actually hard naming it in the code.

This is all in swift. This is as far as I have been able to get:

```
class NewPictures: UIImageView {

  static var hotDog: UIImage = UIImage(named: "tom.jpg")!

  static var hotDogShot :UIImageView = UIImageView(image: hotDog)

  init() {
      super.init(image: NewPictures.hotDog)}

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

}
```

So I want a user to be able to press a button on the UI and an image pop up, eventually I'd like said user to be able to choose an image from their photos but I'd be happy to get any photo to pop up.

I can get one to pop up, and then it bounces around when I hit the button again, but I want multiple instances of the same class.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the code where you instance this subclass?

Answer (score 0):

I thought that when I wanted to create an instance of something the variable name would have to be different every time.

That isn't the case, so once I just put in let something = MyClass()

it worked like a charm.

Comment: When you work with objects, a variable name is just like a physical label on a cardboard box. If you peel the label off box #1 and stick it on box #2, it doesn't mean the original box is destroyed. It's still physically there.

Comment: very good point - appreciate that! I was thinking in terms of declaring variables.. you can't declare a variable more than once so how would a button work after the second time you try and create it.

my thinking was wrong, obviously